# am i pronouncing the "r" in earlier correctly

Tags: pronunciation, accent, american-accent

I am trying to learn American accent.

I have a problem with the "R" sound.

Could you please listen to this sample I have recorded.

http://www.filedropper.com/untitled_20

Also, could you please tell me what the sentence I have said, just to be sure that I am speaking clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand all but one word of it very easily:

*"Earlier, we considered two simple rules for crossing a road.  Let's now (widen?) said road."*

As far as your accent - Your vowel sounds in "earlier" are off.   Maybe the simplest way to describe it is that when you begin the word, you give the first "er" two syllables - First I hear a long A sound, such as the one you later use between *crossing* and *road.*  Then you have an "ur" sound like the one you use in the word *considERed*.  In American English *earlier* is pronounced using only that second sound - the one from *considERed.*  You basically got it right in the third syllable of *earlier* - the "er" at the end.

Remedy:  You are pronouncing *earlier* as if it had four syllables:  "Ay-ur-lee-ur."  Drop the first one entirely - "ur-lee-ur."

Comment: I said "Lets now add a third rule". it seems that my accent was so terrible :(, I will try your answer and give you another recording. plus one

Comment: Ahh - I hear it now.  The pronunciation of "Let's now add a third rule" isn't all that terrible, but your stress is off.  Stressing the "now" slightly, and the "third" heavily will help carry along the structure you set up in the previous sentence (two rules -> third rule.)  "Let's _now_ add a **_third_** rule."